# Calling WS that returns complexType

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I have to call a WS that returns a complexType like this

```
<WSResponse xmlns="http://uri.org/">
  <ConvertResult>
    <param1>string</param1>
    <param2>string</param2>
    <param3>int</param3>
    <param4>string</param4>
  </ConvertResult>
</WSResponse>
```

the WSDL for that part is

```
<s:element name="WSResponse">
    <s:complexType>
       <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ConvertResult" type="tns:ISO"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ISO">
   <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="param1" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="param2" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="param3" type="s:int"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="param4" type="s:string"/>
   </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
```

I'm using this code in java to do it

```
Service service = new Service();
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();

call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, true);
call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://uri.org/" + WebMethod);

call.setTargetEndpointAddress(endpointURL);
call.setOperationName(new QName("http://uri.org/", WebMethod));
call.addParameter(new QName("http://uri.org/","param"), XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN); 
call.setReturnType(new QName("","ISO"), ISO.class);

Object params[]={ param };
Object ret = call.invoke(params);
```

where ISO is

```
class ISO implements Serializable {
    String param1;
    String param2;
    int param3;
    String param4;
}
```

But I get

> Deserializing parameter 'ConvertResult':  could not find deserializer for type ISO

I haven't work with complexTypes before in WS calls, so I'm a little lost. How am I suppose to receive that response? I've tried adding this to the call

```
BeanSerializerFactory bsf =   new BeanSerializerFactory(ISO.class,new QName("","ISO"));
BeanDeserializerFactory bdf = new BeanDeserializerFactory(ISO.class,new QName("","ISO"));
call.registerTypeMapping(ISO.class,new QName("","ISO"), bsf, bdf);
```

as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884872/could-not-find-deserializer-for-type-error) suggested, but I get

> SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.

I guess I'm kind of mixed up with all the solutions I've tried (nothing works). I know the ws works, because I've tried changing that `complexType` for a simple string (with the corresponding change in the ws) and it works, so I must be doing something wrong with the return type.

Can you help me out?

PD: I've tried adding and removing the namespace for the mapping and beanDeserializer, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to solve this problem:

I was really confused on how to map the WSDL to java code. My mistake was to do the ISO class by hand. I finally created that stub with the code from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/475045/Web-Services/java/call-WSDL-Java-main-issues)

```
import org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java;

public class Random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] params = new String[] {"-v", "-D", "-o c:/projects/WSTest", "http://URL to WSDL file"};  
        try  {  
            WSDL2Java.main(params);  
        } catch (Exception ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace()  
        }  
    }
}
```

That's WSDL2Java and it saves lives. After that I got a bunch of classes inside the folder, copied them to my project, changed the package references, and voila. The final code was this one

```
call.addParameter(new QName("http://uri.org/","param"), XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN); 
call.setReturnType(new QName("","ISO"), ISO.class);

Object params[]={ param };
ISO ret = (ISO) call.invoke(params);
```

I realize this may be simple for a lot of people, but I got really confused and the different errors I got and different solutions just confused me more. I'm leaving this here in case it helps someone.

This [doc](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Consuming_Web_Services_with_Axis) may be useful to somebody too.