# SOAP using Apache Axis 1...ColdFusion Error

Tags: java, apache, soap, coldfusion

So I am trying to make a SOAP call, and I need to use Apache Axis 1 because the endpoint uses RPC Encoding.  I am having issues because on the response, I am getting this error:

> Could not find deserializer for type
>   {http://rpc.xml.coldfusion}QueryBean

I assume web service is trying to convert the response into a QueryBean, but cannot, since I do not have that object in my app (I also tried printing out the response, but I got the same error).

My code is below.  Not sure what to do, so if anyone has any ideas on how to solve this, or what exactly a QueryBean is, I would love to hear them.  Thanks!

```
        String endpoint =     "[endpoint hidden]";

        Service service = new Service();
        Call  call    = (Call) service.createCall();

        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
        call.setOperationName(new QName("http://rpc.xml.coldfusion", "getReportContent"));

        String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] { "142", "5088721" });
        System.out.println("Response: " + ret + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
```

**Update:**

I found a jar that contained QueryBean (axis-client.jar), and I figured that would solve my problem.  I still get the same error though.  I tried debugging, and got a bigger stack trace, so I figured I would post it here:

```
2016-08-12 11:20:22,266 ERROR [Call:2469] Exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'getReportContentReturn':  could not find deserializer for type {http://rpc.xml.coldfusion}QueryBean
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCHandler.onStartChild(RPCHandler.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:345)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.elderscan.ncoa.service.NCOAWebServiceTest.axisTest(NCOAWebServiceTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'getReportContentReturn':  could not find deserializer for type {http://rpc.xml.coldfusion}QueryBean
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'getReportContentReturn':  could not find deserializer for type {http://rpc.xml.coldfusion}QueryBean
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCHandler.onStartChild(RPCHandler.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:345)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.elderscan.ncoa.service.NCOAWebServiceTest.axisTest(NCOAWebServiceTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:xxx

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'getReportContentReturn':  could not find deserializer for type {http://rpc.xml.coldfusion}QueryBean
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2470)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.elderscan.ncoa.service.NCOAWebServiceTest.axisTest(NCOAWebServiceTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'getReportContentReturn':  could not find deserializer for type {http://rpc.xml.coldfusion}QueryBean
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCHandler.onStartChild(RPCHandler.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:345)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow uses a Q&A (question and answer) format. It is preferable to post solutions within the official "answer" rather than the "question" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. With the help of this very helpful StackOverflow answer ([Could not find deserializer for type : Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884872/could-not-find-deserializer-for-type-error)) I was able to resolve the error. The REST call worked fine after doing the following:

1. Added the jar containing `QueryBean` (axis-client.jar) to my class path
2. Added the following to my code:

   ```
   Service service = new Service();
   Call  call    = (Call) service.createCall();


   QName q = new QName("http://rpc.xml.coldfusion", "QueryBean");
   BeanSerializerFactory bsf =   new BeanSerializerFactory(QueryBean.class, q);   // step 2
   BeanDeserializerFactory bdf = new BeanDeserializerFactory(QueryBean.class, q);  // step 3
   call.registerTypeMapping(QueryBean.class, q, bsf, bdf); //step 4

   call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
   call.setOperationName(new QName(endpoint, "getReportContent"));
   QueryBean bean = (QueryBean) call.invoke( new Object[] { "142", "5088721" });
   ```